# Mapping blocks in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to map codes to blocks. The blocks are defined by numeric ranges for example AAA0-AAA9 would contain codes AAA0, AAA1, AAA2 etc. The ranges may vary but can be defined in a list for example. I would appreciate help on converting codes in a pandas dataframe to their respective blocks.

See example starting dataframe:

```
d = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'Code': [
'AAA1', 'AAA2', 'AAA3', 'AAA4', 'AAA5', 'CCC2', 'AAA7', 'AAA9', 'BBB1', 'BBB2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

See example desired dataframe (with blocks 'AAA0-9', 'CCC5-9', 'BBB0-5'):

```
d = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'Code': [
'AAA0-9', 'AAA0-9', 'AAA0-9', 'AAA0-9', 'AAA0-9', 'CCC5-9', 'AAA0-9', 'AAA0-9', 'BBB0-5', 'BBB0-5']}
 df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

EDIT: With additional codes. Same concept as above but there are potentially multiple blocks applicable.

```
d = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'Code': ['AAA1 AAA2 AAA3', 'AAA2', 'AAA3 AAA9', 'AAA4', 'AAA5', 'CCC2 CCC3', 'AAA7', 
'AAA9', 'BBB1', 'BBB2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) of first 3 values created by [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) with `dictionary`:

```
d = {'AAA':'AAA0-9', 'CCC':'CCC5-9', 'BBB':'BBB0-5'}
#or generate dict from list
#L = ['AAA0-9', 'CCC5-9', 'BBB0-5']
#d = {x[:3]:x for x in L}

df['Code'] = df['Code'].str[:3].map(d)
print (df)
     Code  ID
0  AAA0-9   1
1  AAA0-9   2
2  AAA0-9   3
3  AAA0-9   4
4  AAA0-9   5
5  CCC5-9   6
6  AAA0-9   7
7  AAA0-9   8
8  BBB0-5   9
9  BBB0-5  10
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['Code'].str[:3])
0    AAA
1    AAA
2    AAA
3    AAA
4    AAA
5    CCC
6    AAA
7    AAA
8    BBB
9    BBB
Name: Code, dtype: object
```

EDIT:

If need also expand values:

```
a = df.Code.str.split()
b = np.repeat(df.ID.values, a.str.len())
c = np.concatenate(a.values)

d = {'AAA':'AAA0-9', 'CCC':'CCC5-9', 'BBB':'BBB0-5'}
df = pd.DataFrame({'Code':c, 'ID':b})
print (df)
    Code  ID
0   AAA1   1
1   AAA2   1
2   AAA3   1
3   AAA2   2
4   AAA3   3
5   AAA9   3
6   AAA4   4
7   AAA5   5
8   CCC2   6
9   CCC3   6
10  AAA7   7
11  AAA9   8
12  BBB1   9
13  BBB2  10
```

---

```
df['Code'] = df['Code'].str[:3].map(d)
print (df)
      Code  ID
0   AAA0-9   1
1   AAA0-9   1
2   AAA0-9   1
3   AAA0-9   2
4   AAA0-9   3
5   AAA0-9   3
6   AAA0-9   4
7   AAA0-9   5
8   CCC5-9   6
9   CCC5-9   6
10  AAA0-9   7
11  AAA0-9   8
12  BBB0-5   9
13  BBB0-5  10
```

Also if dont need change format:

```
df = (df.set_index('ID')['Code']
       .str.split(expand=True)
       .stack()
       .str[:3]
       .map(d)
       .groupby(level=0)
       .apply(' '.join)
       .reset_index(name='Code'))
print (df)
   ID                  Code
0   1  AAA0-9 AAA0-9 AAA0-9
1   2                AAA0-9
2   3         AAA0-9 AAA0-9
3   4                AAA0-9
4   5                AAA0-9
5   6         CCC5-9 CCC5-9
6   7                AAA0-9
7   8                AAA0-9
8   9                BBB0-5
9  10                BBB0-5
```

EDIT1:

If need generate dictionary by ranges:

```
L = ['AAA0-9', 'CCC2-9', 'BBB0-5']
d = (pd.Series(L, index=L)
      .str.extract('(?P<a>\D+)(?P<b>\d)-(?P<c>\d+)', expand=True)
      .set_index('a', append=True)
      .astype(int)
      .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(range(x.b, x.c + 1)), axis=1)
      .stack()
      .astype(int)
      .astype(str)
      .reset_index(name='d')
      .assign(a=lambda x: x.a + x.d)
      .rename(columns={'level_0':'e'})
      .set_index('a')['e']
      .to_dict()
      )

print (d)

{'BBB1': 'BBB0-5', 'CCC6': 'CCC2-9', 'CCC2': 'CCC2-9', 
 'BBB4': 'BBB0-5', 'CCC5': 'CCC2-9', 'BBB2': 'BBB0-5', 
 'CCC4': 'CCC2-9', 'AAA4': 'AAA0-9', 'BBB0': 'BBB0-5', 
 'AAA9': 'AAA0-9', 'BBB3': 'BBB0-5', 'CCC3': 'CCC2-9',
 'AAA0': 'AAA0-9', 'AAA3': 'AAA0-9', 'CCC9': 'CCC2-9', 
 'AAA2': 'AAA0-9', 'BBB5': 'BBB0-5', 'AAA1': 'AAA0-9', 
 'CCC8': 'CCC2-9', 'CCC7': 'CCC2-9', 'AAA8': 'AAA0-9', 
 'AAA7': 'AAA0-9', 'AAA5': 'AAA0-9', 'AAA6': 'AAA0-9'}

 df['Code'] = df['Code'].map(d)
```

Comment: Apologies I have misframed this question slightly. There can be more than one code within the series. I've added an example above.

Comment: Not sure if understand, same solution does not work?

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! Really appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to accommodate arbitrary length codes:

```
df.Code.str.extract('(\D+)', expand=False)

0    AAA
1    AAA
2    AAA
3    AAA
4    AAA
5    CCC
6    AAA
7    AAA
8    BBB
9    BBB
Name: Code, dtype: object
```

You can even conveniently name the columns

```
df.Code.str.extract('(?P<Block>\D+)(?P<Num>\d+)', expand=True)

  Block Num
0   AAA   1
1   AAA   2
2   AAA   3
3   AAA   4
4   AAA   5
5   CCC   2
6   AAA   7
7   AAA   9
8   BBB   1
9   BBB   2
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to do this over a a number of blocks. For example if in the series there was AAA0 AAA4 BBB9?

Comment: IIUC yes.  Should work as I've laid out.  If it doesn't then I don't understand the scenario.  You should edit your question and add it.